# Hover on first 24 childs of an element with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to add a hover on the first 24 childs that adds a fill on the 24 seperate elements of an other element.

Like so:

```
$('tr td:nth-child(1)').mouseover(function(){
  $('rect:nth-of-type(1)').css("fill", "black" );
});

$('tr td:nth-child(2)').mouseover(function(){  
  $('rect:nth-of-type(2)').css("fill", "black" );
});

$('tr td:nth-child(3)').mouseover(function(){
  $('rect:nth-of-type(3)').css("fill", "black" );
});
```

But i don't want to repeat myself 24 times. Whats the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('tr td:lt(24)').mouseenter(function(){

   var index = $(this).index();
   $('rect').eq( index ).css("fill","black");

});
```

IF you don't have more than 24 elements than you don't need the `:lt()` selector

[Holy bible](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

You can also use the JS method `.slice()` like:

```
$('tr td').slice(0,24)
```

You can also target the desired element using `.eq()` ( or `:eq()-selector` ) and than go for a collection of previous elements using `.prevAll()`

```
$('tr td:eq(24)').prevAll()
```

Always be as much specific as you can with your target elements selectors using  `#ID`

Comment: Your `.slice()` example is incorrect if there's more than one `tr`.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the `lt` selector:

```
$('tr td:lt(24)')
```

http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/

Comment: nice. I learned something new. I searched for this but didn't find it.. my google fu needs some work. I figured jQuery would have something!

Answer (score 0):

This would perform better using event delegation on the enclosing table:

```
$('#mytable').on('mouseover', 'td:lt(24)', function() {
    var n = $(this).index();
    $('rect').eq(n).css('fill', 'black');
});
```

this is more efficient than binding the same function to every matching element.